# Ascending vs Descending sort order with Async.js sortBy

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to sort an array of objects by their date property using Async.sortBy, from most recent to oldest. A bit of googleing suggests that I reverse sort order by passing obj.date * -1 in the callback instead of obj.date, but this does not have the intended effect. Obviously because the result of that is just NaN.

My dates are in the form 2012-07-12 using today's date as an example.

Sorry fr the brevity and lack of code samples, I'm on the road on my iPad at the moment.

I could just reverse the output array of the sorting I guess but that's not a particularly nice solution.

```
[{title: "title", date: "2012-07-12"}, {title: "title2", date: "2011-07-12"}]
```

Comment: From your question I understand that you have your the date field in string format. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. It's an array of JavaScript objects, and each object has key "date" with value in string format, yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this solution?

```
async.sortBy([{title: "title", date: "2012-07-12"}, {title: "title2", date: "2011-07-12"}], function(myObject, callback){
    return parseInt( myObject.date.split( '-' ).join(''), 10 ) * -1;
}, function(err, results){ ... });
```

in converts the date string into a sortable integer and reverses it by multipling with -1.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/austinyun-test1

Performance test of array.reverse vs parseInt. array.reverse is quite a bit faster, and has the benefit of being shorter.